How to make a (GeoTools) StyleLayer from a (Geotools) TileLayer
I'm trying to connect to OpenStreetMap by connecting a GeoTools gt- tileService to the
URL = http://tile.openstreetmap.org, but an excepion accurs when I'm trying to cast the layer to a StyleLayer .
the code:
String baseURL = "http://tile.openstreetmap.org";
TileService service = new OSMService("OSM", baseURL);
MapView.map.addLayer(new TileLayer(service));

This works fine, but then I try to do this:
StyleLayer styleLayer=null;
    if (!(layer instanceof GridReaderLayer) && 
        !(layer instanceof org.geotools.tile.util.TileLayer)) {
        FeatureLayer l = (FeatureLayer) layer;
        styleLayer = (StyleLayer) l;
    } else if (layer instanceof GridReaderLayer){
        styleLayer = (StyleLayer) layer;
    }
     else if (layer instanceof org.geotools.tile.util.TileLayer){
         styleLayer = (StyleLayer) layer; //Here it BLOWS, what should I cast it to (cast to GridReaderLayer doesn't work either)?
    }

How can I make a StyleLayer from a TileLayer?
This is the stack trace:
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.geotools.tile.util.TileLayer cannot be cast to class org.geotools.map.StyleLayer (org.geotools.tile.util.TileLayer and org.geotools.map.StyleLayer are in unnamed module of loader 'appjava.lang.ClassCastException: class org.geotools.tile.util.TileLayer cannot be cast to class org.geotools.map.StyleLayer (org.geotools.tile.util.TileLayer and org.geotools.map.StyleLayer are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.geotools.jdbcconnection.mapview.MapLayerTableCellRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(MapLayerTableCellRenderer.java:423)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.updateLayoutState(BasicListUI.java:1439)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.maybeUpdateLayoutState(BasicListUI.java:1389)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.getPreferredSize(BasicListUI.java:648)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(JComponent.java:1680)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.ScrollPaneLayout.layoutContainer(ScrollPaneLayout.java:795)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1537)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1526)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1722)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1731)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1731)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1731)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1731)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1731)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1731)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1731)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1657)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateUnconditionally(Container.java:1694)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.show(Window.java:1050)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1716)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1663)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1031)
    at org.geotools.jdbcconnection.mapview.JMapFrame.setVisible(JMapFrame.java:433)
    at org.geotools.jdbcconnection.mapview.MapView$1.run(MapView.java:1089)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)')
    at org.geotools.jdbcconnection.mapview.MapLayerTableCellRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(MapLayerTableCellRenderer.java:423)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.updateLayoutState(BasicListUI.java:1439)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.maybeUpdateLayoutState(BasicListUI.java:1389)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.getPreferredSize(BasicListUI.java:648)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(JComponent.java:1680)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.ScrollPaneLayout.layoutContainer(ScrollPaneLayout.java:795)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1537)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1526)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1722)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1731)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1731)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1731)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1731)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1731)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1731)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1731)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1657)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateUnconditionally(Container.java:1694)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.show(Window.java:1050)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1716)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1663)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1031)
    at org.geotools.jdbcconnection.mapview.JMapFrame.setVisible(JMapFrame.java:433)
    at org.geotools.jdbcconnection.mapview.MapView$1.run(MapView.java:1089)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)


As far as I know you can't make a StyledLayer from an OSM TileLayer since it doesn't take a style, and is descended from DirectLayer.
